# Flexslider change buttons

Tags: flexslider

is there anyway I can change the little navigate buttons into text buttons on flexslider? I can't find it anywhere on internet.

Answer (score 11):

To use an image as the navigation button:

```
.flex-direction-nav a:before  { 
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    background: url('../path-to-image/flexslider-left.png') no-repeat;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before  { 
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    background: url('../path-to-image/flexslider-right.png') no-repeat;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the prevText and nextText properties, like this (I'm using arrows but you can change to whatever text you want):

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    prevText: "&#8592;",
    nextText: "&#8594;"
});
```

And then in `flexslider.css` remove the `background-image` and `text-indent` properties from `.flex-direction-nav a`.

Hope it helps.